# I want the perfect way to filter my data using stored procedure and textboxes

Tags: sql-server, database, filter

I want the perfect way to filter my data using stored procedure and pass values from textboxes. Can anybody help me to make it perfect and short?

This is my stored procedure:

[image]

These are the text boxes which takes values from user and pass to stored procedure.

[image]

I want to know how to handle this

Comment: why you are writing stored procedure for this simpler problem, the good way would be to handle this in your c#/Java code.

Answer (score 0):

When I have to code something like this, I use IsNull():

```
Where vendor_name = Isnull(@vendorname, vendor_name)
And mat_name = Isnull(@matname, mat_name)
And manual_mat = Isnull(@manualman, manual_mat)
```

I don't know if that's "the perfect way" (what is your definition of "perfect"?), but it's efficient.